# Change cell value according to values within another column [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Names Value COLA COLB COLC
A     100   0    4    1
B     NaN   0    2    1
C     20    3    0    0
D     1     0    1    0
E     300   3    0    0
```

And I would like to change all the `COLA,B` and `C` values (except the 0) :

- to **1** if the `Value col > 30`
- to **2** if the `Value col <=30` or `NaN`.

I should then get

```
Names Value COLA COLB COLC
A     100   0    1    1
B     NaN   0    2    2
C     20    2    0    0
D     1     0    2    0
E     300   1    0    0
```

Does someone have a sugestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chain condition used for broadcasting - assign mask from `Series` to multiple columns, for set `0` multiple ouput to boolean mask for set `0`:

```
cols = ['COLA','COLB','COLC']

df[cols] = np.where(df['Value'].gt(30).to_numpy()[:, None], 1, 2) * df[cols].ne(0)
print (df)
  Names  Value  COLA  COLB  COLC
0     A  100.0     0     1     1
1     B    NaN     0     2     2
2     C   20.0     2     0     0
3     D    1.0     0     2     0
4     E  300.0     1     0     0
```